# TabView swipe gesture doesn't work on View with LongPressGesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am attempting to add a `LongPressGesture` to a view that acts as a button which brings up a sheet. When it's a `Button` it works fine and the swipe works between views. But when I remove the button and add a `LongPressGesture` to the view, only the long press works and you can no longer swipe left and right on the `TabView` and only swipe above or below the view (example below).

I assume there's some precedence of gestures here, could anyone enlighten me on what the process is to have the `TabView` swiping gesture work with precedence over the `LongPressGesture`?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toggleSheet: Bool = false
    @GestureState private var isDetectingLongPress: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("1")
                .font(Font.system(size: 300))
                .gesture(
                    LongPressGesture().updating(self.$isDetectingLongPress) {
                        currentState, gestu[![enter image description here][1]][1]reState, transaction in
                        gestureState = currentState
                    }
                        .onEnded {
                            _ in
                            self.toggleSheet.toggle()
                        }
                )
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$toggleSheet) {
                    Rectangle()
                }
                
            Text("2")
                .font(Font.system(size: 300))
                .gesture(
                    LongPressGesture().updating(self.$isDetectingLongPress) {
                        currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                        gestureState = currentState
                    }
                        .onEnded {
                            _ in
                            self.toggleSheet.toggle()
                        }
                )
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$toggleSheet) {
                    Circle()
                }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Hard to see in the giphy, but when swiping my mouse is above or below the view.

[image]